# How to download a file to server PHP?

Tags: php, download, webserver, filesystems

Is it possible with PHP script to have the script download a file on a remote server to my web server?

I have my own webserver and domain. I want to put a php script on that domain, that will download a file from a remote server onto my server's filesystem. Is this possible?

-Jim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you'll need write permissions somewhere on the file system (where you want to save this file), [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) can take a URL as its argument, you just need to write the resulting string to a new file

I'd personally do this by calling out to the shell and invoking `wget` or similar if i were on a linux box.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with `file_get_contents()`, `fgets()`, or `readfile()`, depending on your server configuration.

Create a file locally and dump the data from any of those functions, into your new local file.

Comment: file_put_contents("Tmpfile.zip", file_get_contents("http://someurl/file.zip"));   from a similar question

Answer (score 0):

I thinkk this is what you are refering to:

```
<?php
$file = 'http://example.com/example.txt';
$newfile = 'example.txt.bak';

if (!copy($file, $newfile)) {
    echo "failed to copy $file...\n";
}
?>
```

Any good?

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

You could also use CURL if you need more control over the request type/headers