# how to download a file in php?

Tags: php, client-server, download

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to download a file to server PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938504/how-to-download-a-file-to-server-php)

hello,

i'm trying to write a simple php code to download a file from a server.....can someone guide me how to do it....i've trying to find some guide but each of them is so confusing that i can make anything out of it.......

any help will be highly appreciated....

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to download a simple text file, you can use file(), or file_get_contents():

```
file('http://url/to/file.txt') will return an array of lines
file_get_contents('http://url/to/file.txt') will return the file as a string
```

Alternatively, when the data type is binary for example, you can use the following snippet, found at [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php)

```
<?php
$filename = "/usr/local/something.txt"; // This can also be an url to an external file
$handle = fopen($filename, "rb");
$contents = stream_get_contents($handle);
fclose($handle);
?>
```

Now you could for example write the contents to a file.

Hope this helps.

[Edit] Apologies, I pasted the wrong snippet, this should be the right one

Answer (score 0):

The manual page on [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/file_get_contents) provides a full working example.

If you encounter problems with it, you can ask a specific question.

Answer (score 0):

Just make use of the php copy function:

```
if (!copy('http://www.example.com/file.jpg', '/path/to/dir/newfile.jpg')) 
{
    echo "failed to copy $file...\n";
}
```